# JBoss EAR with multiple WARs and shared dependencies including a common datasource file

Tags: jboss, packaging, ear

We are going from a single WAR to multiple WARs to be repackaged within an EAR file in JBoss. I would like to be able to do the following:

- Move common libraries to under the root of the new EAR so that they don't have to be duplicated within each of the WARs (I suppose under $EAR_ROOT/lib?).
- Move the *-ds.xml file from under $JBOSS_HOME/server//deploy to under the EAR so that the datasource is scoped to the application (at least from a packaging standpoint - I realize there is no preventing a JNDI lookup from other WAR, that's okay).
- Repackage the Hibernate DAOs and dependencies to a new to-be-shared JAR file and put them in the common location as well (to be shared by both the WARs).

I have some sense on what needs to happen but could use some help so that I don't have to create all of this structure and the related Ant/Maven targets/goals from scratch. For instance, should the datasource file be referenced in jboss-app.xml or in application.xml directly?

There seem to be multiple ways of skinning this cat and I am looking for a nice, clean example to do this (in the interest of not having to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 0):

Use JBoss Developer Studio, it does all that for you